# Get Child Component from ListItem Sencha Touch2

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2, sencha-touch-2.2

**List Template:**

```
var templ = new Ext.XTemplate(
      '<tpl if="isActive">',
            '<div style="color:red" class="',
            Ext.baseCSSPrefix + 'list-sortablehandle',
            '">',
        '</tpl>',    
    '<b>Name: {text}</b>',
        '<tpl if="isActive">',
            '<b>{text}</b></div>',
        '</tpl>',
            {
                // XTemplate configuration:
                compiled: true,
                // member functions:
                isitem2: function (name) {
                    return name == 'item2';
                },
            }
);
```

I can able to get the list item from specific index using

```
var targetItem = list.getItemAt(targetIndex);
```

but

```
targetItem.down('.x-list-sortablehandle')
```

**through expection**

Object [object Object] has no method 'down'

I want to know whether the specific element in present inside the listmItem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

getItemAt is probably returning a SimpleListItem (assuming you aren't setting anything custom), which does not have a down method. What you probably want to do is grab the element from that, so instead of **targetItem.down** try using **targetItem.element.down**.